# If/Else TextView actions iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `textview` in my `viewcontroller`.  The text will change on the `textview`, but what I want to be able to do is that. When the `textview` shows a certain word, some code will run.  So I'll have to make an `if/else` statement:

Something like

```
textview == "Dance" {
RUN THIS CODE
}
```

But instead of `textview` I'll put the name of `my textview` there.

How should i start the if/else statement for the textview?

Answer (score 1):

Add textfield Delegate method

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView 
{ 
   if ([<textview name>.text isEqualToString:@"Dance"])
   {
       // here add your code
    }
   else 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: where should i put the name of the textview?

Comment: i mean... i could have multiple textviews... So lets say my textView is named: "Apple". How should i write it now.

Comment: Maulik lets say in my first entry on textView, I entered "Test". Now In my next entry on same textView, I added "Dance". See the problem? You are comparing it literally. You should instead look for substring dance in complete text

Answer (score 1):

you can create an IBOutlet of your textView (In light of your changed requirement) to know if the textView editing is the one you want to observe. Let's say you name that outlet `self.yourTargetTextView`, then this is what you want in delegate.

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView 
{ 
   if(textView==self.yourTargetTextView)
   {
       NSString *string = textView.text;
       if ([string rangeOfString:@"dance"].location == NSNotFound) {
             NSLog(@"string does not contain dance, no code needs to run");
          } 
       else {
             NSLog(@"string contains dance!, lets run some code");
            }

    }
    else
    {
      //For other textViews
    }

}
```

Or alternatively you can use tags to distinguish between different textViews.. Let's say you assign tag to your target textView like:

```
self.yourTargetTextView.tag = 89267;//You can also do this through IB
```

Then you can write your delegate method like this:

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView 
    { 
       if(textView.tag==89267)
       {
           NSString *string = textView.text;
           if ([string rangeOfString:@"dance"].location == NSNotFound) {
                 NSLog(@"string does not contain dance, no code needs to run");
              } 
           else {
                 NSLog(@"string contains dance!, lets run some code");
                }

        }
       else
       {
          //For other textViews
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement UITextviewDelegate method.set textview object delegate to self and class should confirm to Protocol

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
  // if else condition

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give UITextView Tag. According to tag you can put switch or if-else. On **textViewDidBeginEditing** do it.

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView 
{ 
   if (textView.tag == 10)
   {
       // here add your code
    }
   else 
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting unique tags for all textviews. Suppose you apple text view tag value is 123.

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView 
{ 
   if(textView.tag == 123){
     if ([textView.text isEqualToString:@"Dance"])
   {
       // true condition code goes here.
    }
   else 
    {
      // else part goes here if necessary
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below textView Delegate method:

This method will be called when textView text will change, where you can check whatever you want.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"something"]) {
        NSLog(@"do whatever you like here");
        return NO; // or YES, whatever you like
    }
    else{

        return YES; // or NO, whatever you like
    }

    return YES;
}
```